# Feature selection/extraction for simple rule-based classifier

Tags: object, detection

Suppose I have to detect whether or not an image has a Sable Antelope in it or not. Now I have a database full of images, some of which contains the Sable. In all images (that has the Sable in it) the Sable is seen from the side. Now further suppose I somehow find a way to detect if there are horns in the image, any kind of horns, with varying shapes and color (just suppose).

Now I do some further image processing on the images that do contain horns. I determine if they are twisting or straight and maybe how long they are if they come out as straight. Then I take that value of how long it is and I use it in the classifier as a rule. Say between 10 and 15 is Sable Antelope, otherwise not.

What I want to know is, what is what I did there called? Finding the horn length and determining if it belongs to a class or not. Was it feature extraction or feature selection. Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the length of horns and measuring the colour of object, and such, is called [feature extraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_extraction).

Deciding which features to extract and use for classification is called [feature selection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection) (e.g., do not use the colour as it does not lead to good performance).

Deciding if a sample belongs to a class or not based on the selected extracted features is called [classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification).